# Heroku PostgreSQL 1700 databases

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

I got PostgresSQL on Heroku because I'd like to store data that I capture in my web app. It took me a while to learn how to use docker so I got distracted, I finally got round to connecting my web app to postgres. I found the credentials on the online data page and connected through pg admin 3 to my server. However there seems to be 1746 databases on my server with 1753 login/group roles. My database is a series of letters and numbers that is hidden away amongst the other 1736 databases and is hard to find. When I go to click on any other database it tells me I don't have permissions. Why can I see so many databases on my heroku app? How do I get rid of them all? They all have individual owners, are they even all mine? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go in the connection settings advanced tab and change DB restrictions to the name of your database.